# Update Route Entry On another DD-WRT upon New IP address (WAN) SSH linux

Tags: linux, route, dd-wrt

I have two routers on two different gateways/ISPs but on the same local subnet (192.168.).

If router A (192.168.1.1) gets IP address from the ISP (for example 24.64.10.15, non-static), I would like router A to login router B (192.168.1.2) (via ssh or telnet) and update the Routing Entry.

#### Example:

Router B (192.168.1.2)
Set number: 1
Route Name: routename
Metric: 0
Destination LAN Net:  24.64.10.15
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.255
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Inference: LAN & WLAN

Comment: Do you know RIP? Why using SSH or telnet?